# SSH to Remote Server Bash Programming

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I programmed a script which SSH to remote server and get status of GPU server by executing following "nvidia-smi", well that was just a description and purpose of script, but the question is I run this as "root" which can ssh to another server passwordless but users can not, how can I program the script to let user to run the script and get status? of course without entering password to remote server, any authentication can I use?

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="gpuserver01\ngpuserver02"
SCRIPTS="nvidia-smi"

echo -e "which GPU server do you want to check?\n$HOSTS\n"-----------------""
echo "Please Enter Numebr of GPU Server"

read ans

#for HOSTNAME in $ans ; do

if [ $ans = '1' ]; then
HOSTNAME="gpuserver01"
ssh ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPTS}"
else

HOSTNAME="gpuserver02"
ssh ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPTS}"
fi

#done
```

Thank you.

Comment: Note: the equality operator is only a single `=`; bash unfortunately accepts `==`, but that breaks on other shells. Don't spread the `==` non-compliant script disease. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Noted, just fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can give permissions to your script for other users to run as root privileges.

run `visudo`, add below;

```
Cmnd_Alias      CUSTOM_CMD=/path/to/script/myscript.sh
myUser1         ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:CUSTOM_CMD
```

if other users have same group.Let say `otherUsers`

```
Cmnd_Alias      CUSTOM_CMD=/path/to/script/myscript.sh
%otherUsers         ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:CUSTOM_CMD
```

Comment: I have some follow up questions. Is there any way to hide the contents of the script so that those who execute it cannot cat it (chmod 711) maybe? Is there anyway that a user of the script could use this to ssh to the remote server to gain console access? The OP doesn't want users to gain ssh according to their comment on another answer. (and ssh as root is probably extra-devastating).

Comment: Yes, chmod 711 works.  If your script does not contain any vulnerabilities, users will not gain any access.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add normal user to remote host (example gpuuser01).
2. Create SSH keys for that user. [1] Then check, you can log in to  gpuuser01 without password.
3. Create new script on remote host (eg. gpuserver01), with setuid flag [2], that will run nvidia-smi.
4. Now you can connect to remote host and execute your script as root wihout password.
5. Rewrite your script (that one from question).

[1] https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews

[2] http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-bsd-linux-setuid-file/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Here is the thing, users login to the login node and I want them to execute the script to see status of GPU servers without let them SSH to server, it is just like users by executing the script sending kinda agent to remote servers to fetch some status up.

Comment: You can set your script as login shell. So they wont see bash shell, but output of your app when they log in to account.